# Unable to view UITableView Cell ContentView after upgrade to Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, xcode7.2

[image]

After the first cell the content cuts off although the the content is clearly there when I view it through the Document Outline. It's not visible when I scroll in my table view. However when I build the content successfully appears on the simulator and devices running iOS 9.2.1 and earlier. This is incredibly bothersome since I need to add more cells to my table view.

I've tried disabling size classes but it doesn't resolve the issue.

Comment: So in short, you can't see your cells' contents in the storyboard?

Comment: If so, could you post an image of what you're seeing in your question?  There more info we have the better we can help!

Comment: yes in short. I've added a screenshot

Comment: Ok, so that massive blue bit I assume to be a UIImage...?

Comment: Yes it's a UIImageView

Comment: And the bit underneath is the same UIImageView?  So where exactly does your first cell end, and the others begin

Comment: The first cell ends after the small UIImageView

Comment: Right yeah, I guessed so... where the separator is.  So your large UIImageView is extending outwith its cell - have you checked it's definitely not covering your other cells?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98181/discussion-between-hyperion-and-daisy-r).